# Swift how variable declaration works

Tags: ios, swift3

Can some one please explain to me how it works

```
var count: Int?
count = 1
if let count = count {
//do something.
}
```

Why there is no compiler error at `if let count = count` as we already created a variable named count as `var count: Int?`. How come two variables with same name possible?

Comment: scope of second `count` is only within that block. If you want to use other one you can use `self.count` inside that block(assuming it is a property on `self`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift treated as both variables as a different one. The "count" that declared first can be treated as global one while the constant "count" is only available inside if condition, so it can't access outside if condition.

Answer (score 1):

**Optional Variable:** It can contain a value or a Nil value. `Nil` represents the absence of a value or nothing

```
var count: Int? // Optional Variable
```

Here variable `count` is `global variable`.

**Optional Binding:** It is the way by which we try to retrieve a values from a chain of optional variable.

```
if let count = count {
   //do something.
}
```

Here constant `count` value is available only with in the `scope`. It cannot be accessed outside the scope.

Answer (score 0):

This is called optional binding

```
if let constantName = someOptional {
    statements
}
```

someOptional is checked to see if it's nil or has data. If it's nil, the if-statement just doesn't get executed. If there's data, the data gets unwrapped and assigned to constantName for the scope of the if-statement. Then the code inside the braces is executed.

Comment: I understand this is optional binding, but I was confused by the fact that there was two variables with same name exists. But now it is clear that the scope is different for these variables.